# Can anyone help me calculate the value of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{p \leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{1}{(p\ln(\frac{x}{p^2}))^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, number-theory, prime-numbers

Can anyone help me get the value of
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{p \leq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{1}{(p\ln(\frac{x}{p^2}))^2}$$

This seems to be either a constant or $0$ given that the infinite sum of $1/p^2$ is a constant (about $0.454$) but I'm not sure how to actually prove this...

Answer (score 1):

Change variables $x\to 2N^4$. Then the problem asks

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{p=1}^{N^2} \frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2 N^4/p^2)}$$

Split the sum into two parts

Part 1:

$$ \sum_{p=1}^{N} \frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2 N^4/p^2)}\leq  \sum_{p=1}^{N} \frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2 N^4/N^2)} =$$
$$ \sum_{p=1}^{N}\frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2 N^2)}\leq \frac{1}{\log^2(2N^2)}\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p^2 }\leq \frac{1}{4\log^2(2N)}\left[1+\sum_{p=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(p-1) }\right]=\frac{1}{2\log^2(2N)} $$

Part 2:

$$ \sum_{p=N+1}^{N^2} \frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2 N^4/p^2)}\leq  \sum_{p=N}^{N^2} \frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2)} \leq $$

$$ \frac{1}{\log^2(2)}\sum_{p=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p^2 }\leq \frac{1}{\log^2(2)}\sum_{p=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(p-1) }=\frac{1}{(N-1)\log^2(2)}$$

Putting it together we have

$$0\leq \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{p=1}^{N^2} \frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2 N^4/p^2)}\leq \lim_{N\to\infty} \left[\frac{1}{2\log^2(2N)}+\frac{1}{(N-1)\log^2(2)}\right]=0$$

We conclude

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{p=1}^{N^2} \frac{1}{p^2 \log^2(2 N^4/p^2)}=0$$